# How do I combine AUDIO group with VIDEO stream and produce a new .ts file using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Here is the input manifest:

```
$ curl 'https://example.net/ipadlive/index_new.m3u8?sessionid=81893121496608402793&ipaddress=x.x.x.x&callsign=YYYY&hubid=51&zipcode='
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="group",NAME="eng",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="en",URI="https://example.net/ipadlive/06_new.m3u8?cdnHost=da148.cdn.iptv.example.net&sessionid=81893121496608402793&ipaddress=x.x.x.x&callsign=CHAN&hubid=51&zipcode=&countycode=null&fta=null&optimumid=null&devicename=&devicetype=0&osver=&res=&fps="
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="group",NAME="spa",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="en",URI="https://example.net/ipadlive/07_new.m3u8?cdnHost=da148.cdn.iptv.example.net&sessionid=81893121496608402793&ipaddress=x.x.x.x&callsign=CHAN&hubid=51&zipcode=&countycode=null&fta=null&optimumid=null&devicename=&devicetype=0&osver=&res=&fps="
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=479776,RESOLUTION=240x180,CODECS="avc1.42c00c,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group"
https://example.net/ipadlive/01_new.m3u8?cdnHost=da148.cdn.iptv.example.net&sessionid=81893121496608402793&ipaddress=x.x.x.x&callsign=CHAN&hubid=51&zipcode=&countycode=null&fta=null&optimumid=null&devicename=&devicetype=0&osver=&res=&fps=
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=780576,RESOLUTION=320x240,CODECS="avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group"
https://example.net/ipadlive/02_new.m3u8?cdnHost=da148.cdn.iptv.example.net&sessionid=81893121496608402793&ipaddress=x.x.x.x&callsign=CHAN&hubid=51&zipcode=&countycode=null&fta=null&optimumid=null&devicename=&devicetype=0&osver=&res=&fps=
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1079872,RESOLUTION=480x360,CODECS="avc1.42c01e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group"
https://example.net/ipadlive/03_new.m3u8?cdnHost=da148.cdn.iptv.example.net&sessionid=81893121496608402793&ipaddress=x.x.x.x&callsign=CHAN&hubid=51&zipcode=&countycode=null&fta=null&optimumid=null&devicename=&devicetype=0&osver=&res=&fps=
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1682976,RESOLUTION=640x480,CODECS="avc1.42c01e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group"
https://example.net/ipadlive/04_new.m3u8?cdnHost=da148.cdn.iptv.example.net&sessionid=81893121496608402793&ipaddress=x.x.x.x&callsign=CHAN&hubid=51&zipcode=&countycode=null&fta=null&optimumid=null&devicename=&devicetype=0&osver=&res=&fps=
```

I've never seen this before where the audio stream is a separate url than a video stream listed in the manifest.

Is there a way I can combine an audio stream and a specific video stream to produce a new stream that has both audio and video in it?

I was doing something like this:

`ffmpeg -i <manifest> -c copy test.m3u8` and I don't get any audio.

I've tried changing `<manifest>` to an individual video stream, but then no audio. If I change it to an AUDIO stream I get no video.

Comment: You can try multiple `-i` for both individual streams. `ffmpeg -i yourVideo -i yourAudio -c copy someOutput.ts`...

Comment: That got me audio and video but the audio is out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the problem of combining an **audio** .ts file with its accompanying **video** .ts file.  I was able to solve it using the following method for Windows users. [see - [Video resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=42&v=UDIMVp4jWXo&feature=emb_title) ]

1) You will need to download the **ffmpeg library** that will allow Windows to combine both files together.  In my case I was running Windows 8 (32 bit OS) and chose a static build:[image: my OS download requirements]

2) I then opened notepad and wrote the following code once ffmpeg was installed:
`ffmpeg -i VIDEO.ts -i AUDIO.ts -c:v copy -c:a copy OUTPUT.mp4`

I saved the notepad file as "joiner.bat"

**NB: this bat file must present in the same folder as your separate audio and video ts files in order to combine them!!!**

3) Once the bat file is in the same folder as your audio and video ts files you can double click on the joiner.bat file to combine the audio and video ts files into a single **mp4** (OUTPUT.mp4) file.

I hope this helps the more novice types among us.  Yes I'm still a n00b after many years - don't worry! ;)